# How can I add 2 buildService (upload and header) to apollo federation?

Tags: apollo-server, apollo-federation

Is there any option to add both header and upload to buildService in apollo federation?
I want my headers for authentication and upload for uploading file. buildService does not support return object.

```
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  buildService({ name, url }) {
    return new RemoteGraphQLDataSource({
      url,
      willSendRequest({ request, context }: { request: any; context: any }) {
        request?.http?.headers?.set(
          "authorization",
          context.auth ? context.auth : ""
        );
        request?.http?.session?.set(
          "session",
          context.session ? context.session : ""
        );
        request?.http?.sessionStore?.set(
          "sessionStore",
          context.sessionStore ? context.sessionStore : ""
        );
      },
    });
  },
});
```

how can I also add [upload file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@profusion/apollo-federation-upload) to my buildService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, if you extend the FileUploadDataSource somehow works:

```
import {
  ApolloGateway,
  GraphQLDataSourceProcessOptions,
} from '@apollo/gateway';
import { Fetcher } from '@apollo/utils.fetcher';
import FileUploadDataSource from '@profusion/apollo-federation-upload';
import { FileUploadDataSourceArgs } from '@profusion/apollo-federation-upload/build/FileUploadDataSource';
import { GraphQLResponse } from 'apollo-server-types';

class AuthenticationAndUpload extends FileUploadDataSource {
  constructor(config: FileUploadDataSourceArgs) {
    super(config);
    const nativeFetcher = this.fetcher;
    const newFetcher: Fetcher = (url, options) => {
      let plainHeaders: Record<string, string> = options?.headers || { '': '' };
      if (options?.headers?.raw) {
        const headers = options.headers as unknown as IterableIterator<
          [string, string]
        >;
        plainHeaders = Object.fromEntries<string>(headers) as Record<
          string,
          string
        >;
      }
      return nativeFetcher(url, { ...options, headers: plainHeaders });
    };
    this.fetcher = newFetcher;
  }
  willSendRequest({ request, context }: GraphQLDataSourceProcessOptions) {
    request?.http?.headers?.set(
      'authorization',
      context.request.headers?.authorization
        ? context.request.headers.authorization
        : ''
    );
  }
  didReceiveResponse({
    response,
    context,
  }: {
    response: GraphQLResponse;
    context: GraphQLDataSourceProcessOptions['context'];
  }) {
    return response;
  }
}

const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  buildService({ url }) {
    return new AuthenticationAndUpload({ url });
  },
});
```